# Alternatives to StretchDIBits win32 API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, bitmap, gdi+, stretchdibits

I am using `StretchDIBits` function to draw four different Bitmap's pixeldata(DIBits) to different parts of a window.
`StretchDIBits` immediately displays the copied bits in the window. I was wondering if there was a way to  defer showing the copied bitmap's bits until after all bitmaps are drawn.

Comment: Have you heard of double buffering?

Comment: you mean something like the front and back buffers of a swapchain?

Comment: Something like that should work: render it offscreen and swap buffers when everything has been rendered.

Comment: i was actually thinking of rendering everything in a bitmap and then rendering the bitmap to the window but i didn't want to involve a 5th Bitmap. Also, all my bitmaps would change dynamically within a very short time say like 16 ms or even less. Would double buffering be better than a 5th Bitmap?

Comment: *double buffering* in your case **is** the *5th Bitmap*. *...front and back buffers of a swapchain* is a directX orology

Comment: Why are you obsessively suggesting, that there would be a difference between *double buffering* and *using an n+1-th bitmap*? There is conceptually no difference. Read about [Device Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx), [`CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183489.aspx) followed by [`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488.aspx). And done.

Comment: i was more like asking....by double buffering i actually meant like maintaining two different buffers instead of one bitmap and just wanted to know how that would be different if at all.

Comment: *double buffering* is a **technique** of drawing first to offscreen *buffer*. The *buffer* is just a memory place. In directX there are the *back buffer* and *front buffer*. In windows when you check *double buffering = true* the system does it automatically. In your case the *front buffer* is the window hdc and the offscreen buffer is the 5th bitmap hdc.

Comment: that clarifies things up..thanks a lot!